# Update/Push a local NuGet package from Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget

I've been generating custom/local NuGet packages from the Nuget CLI - no problem there.

I'm wondering if anyone knows of a Visual Studio extension or similar that would allow a NuGet package project to be pushed to the local packages server folder via just a button click? Or does anyone know of a non-CLI way to push a new version of the package to the folder?

TIA

Answer (score 2):

> I'm wondering if anyone knows of a Visual Studio extension or similar that would allow a NuGet package project to be pushed to the local packages server folder via just a button click?

According to the [document on nuget.org](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/guides/install-nuget), you will notice that the feature of publishing packages is supported only in the NuGet CLI.

[image]

So we could not publish package from Package Manager. And AFAIK there is no such Visual Studio extension yet.

> Or does anyone know of a non-CLI way to push a new version of the package to the folder?

If you want to use a non-CLI way to publish package, PowerShell should be a good recommendation. You can use [Powershell script to publish package in Visual Studio](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Create-and-Push-NuGet-c6072402) or [out of Visual Studio](https://dzone.com/articles/using-powershell-publish-nuget).

**Note:** There is a limitation for this method, we need to specify the package ID  in the PowerShell script before publish package.